# Loop to make a basic table for many variables by condition

Tags: r

I am running an experiment where participants are randomly assigned to one of two conditions, and then I collect data on several variables. Here is an example of my code:

```
df <- data.frame(condition =c(1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1),
              var1 = c(6,6,4,7,5,6,6,6,4,7),
              var2 = c(3,4,3,6,7,1,2,1,2,5),
              var3 = c(2,2,6,6,7,1,7,7,3,1),
              var4 = c(6,4,3,6,4,1,3,3,4,4))

df$condition = factor(df$condition, levels = c(-1,1),labels = c("Digital","Physical"))
```

For each variable (var1, var2, etc.) I would like a little table with the count, mean, and standard deviation. This code creates the kind of table that I want:

```
 group_by(df, df$condition) %>% 
  summarise(
    count = n(),
    mean = mean(var1),
    sd = sd(var1))
```

But because I have many variables, I would like to use some kind of loop (or "lapply"?) to create all these tables at once. It would also be great if each table could show the name of the variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
df <- data.frame(condition =c(1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1),
                 var1 = c(6,6,4,7,5,6,6,6,4,7),
                 var2 = c(3,4,3,6,7,1,2,1,2,5),
                 var3 = c(2,2,6,6,7,1,7,7,3,1),
                 var4 = c(6,4,3,6,4,1,3,3,4,4))

df$condition = factor(df$condition, levels = c(-1,1),labels = c("Digital","Physical"))





for (var in names(df)[2:length(names(df))]){

  
  tab <- group_by(df, condition) %>% 
    select(c("condition", var)) %>% 
    dplyr::rename(v = var) %>% 
    summarise(
      count = n(),
      mean = mean(v),
      sd = sd(v) 
      )
  print(var)
  print(tab)
}
```

gives

```
[1] "var1"
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  condition count  mean    sd
  <fct>     <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Digital       5   5.8  1.10
2 Physical      5   5.6  1.14
[1] "var2"
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  condition count  mean    sd
  <fct>     <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Digital       5   2.2  1.64
2 Physical      5   4.6  1.82
[1] "var3"
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  condition count  mean    sd
  <fct>     <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Digital       5   3.8  3.03
2 Physical      5   4.6  2.41
[1] "var4"
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  condition count  mean    sd
  <fct>     <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Digital       5   3    1.22
2 Physical      5   4.6  1.34
>
```

Comment: This looks great, thanks! Is there something I could add to this loop so that all of these tibbles are exported to the same csv file?

Comment: You could use openxlsx to write them to different sheets of an Excel file?

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `summarise` on all the variables, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

group_by(df, condition) %>% 
     summarise(across(everything(), ~ c(count = n(), mean = mean(.), sd = sd(.))))

`summarise()` has grouped output by 'condition'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   condition [2]
  condition  var1  var2  var3  var4
  <fct>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Digital    5     5     5     5   
2 Digital    5.8   2.2   3.8   3   
3 Digital    1.10  1.64  3.03  1.22
4 Physical   5     5     5     5   
5 Physical   5.6   4.6   4.6   4.6 
6 Physical   1.14  1.82  2.41  1.34
```

You can control the output structure  by changing object in the formula, i.e.

```
group_by(df, condition) %>% 
     summarise(across(everything(), ~ data.frame(count = n(), mean = mean(.), sd = sd(.))))
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  condition var1$count $mean   $sd var2$count $mean   $sd var3$count $mean   $sd var4$count $mean   $sd
  <fct>          <int> <dbl> <dbl>      <int> <dbl> <dbl>      <int> <dbl> <dbl>      <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Digital            5   5.8  1.10          5   2.2  1.64          5   3.8  3.03          5   3    1.22
2 Physical           5   5.6  1.14          5   4.6  1.82          5   4.6  2.41          5   4.6  1.34
```

Answer (score 1):

We could still do it my `summarise` using a list:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(condition) %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with("var"), .f = list(n = ~n(),
                                         mean = mean,
                                         sd = sd), na.rm = TRUE))
```

```
  condition var1_n var1_mean var1_sd var2_n var2_mean var2_sd var3_n var3_mean var3_sd var4_n var4_mean var4_sd
      <dbl>  <int>     <dbl>   <dbl>  <int>     <dbl>   <dbl>  <int>     <dbl>   <dbl>  <int>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1        -1      5       5.8    1.10      5       2.2    1.64      5       3.8    3.03      5       3      1.22
2         1      5       5.6    1.14      5       4.6    1.82      5       4.6    2.41      5       4.6    1.34
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `lapply`, the function of choice is `aggregate`, a close relative to the `*apply` family at least. Put in a custom function `f`.

```
f <- \(x) c(n=length(x), mu=mean(x), sd=sd(x))

aggregate(. ~ condition, df, f)
#   condition   var1.n  var1.mu  var1.sd   var2.n  var2.mu  var2.sd   var3.n  var3.mu  var3.sd   var4.n  var4.mu  var4.sd
# 1   Digital 5.000000 5.800000 1.095445 5.000000 2.200000 1.643168 5.000000 3.800000 3.033150 5.000000 3.000000 1.224745
# 2  Physical 5.000000 5.600000 1.140175 5.000000 4.600000 1.816590 5.000000 4.600000 2.408319 5.000000 4.600000 1.341641
```

If you want to aggregate on a specific set of variables (e.g. assembled with `grep`), use list notation instead.

```
aggregate(df[grep('^var', names(df))], df['condition'], f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gtsummary` here if you need to present the results.

Example one below will make one table with all of your variables. Example two will split each variable into its own table (if you need them to be seperate)

```
library(gtsummary)

#example one: 
tbl_summary(df, by = condition,
            type = list(everything()~"continuous"),
            statistic = list(all_continuous()~"{mean} ({sd}) ")) 

#example two:
tbl_summary(df, by = condition,
            type = list(everything()~"continuous"),
            statistic = list(all_continuous()~"{mean} ({sd}) ")) %>% 
      tbl_split(variables = c(var1, var2,var3,var4))
```